# replace an object inside nsmutablearray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, xcode4.3

I have a `NSMutableArray` where i want to replace the sign `|` into a `;` how can i do that?

```
NSMutableArray *paths = [dic valueForKey:@"PATH"];
NSLog(@"pathArr ",  paths)
pathArr (
    (
       "29858,39812;29858,39812;29925,39804;29936,39803;29949,39802;29961,39801;30146,39782;30173,39779;30220,39774;30222,39774|30215,39775;30173,39779;30146,39782;29961,39801;29949,39802;29936,39803;29925,39804;29858,39812;29858,39812;29856,39812;29800,39819;29668,39843;29650,39847;29613,39855;29613,39855;29613,39856;29605,39857;29603,39867;29603,39867;29599,39892;29596,39909;29587,39957;29571,40018;29563,40038;29560,40043"
    )
)
```

**Update**

This is where i got my path from

```
NSArray *BusRoute = alightDesc;
int i;
int count = [BusRoute count];
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{   
    NSLog (@"BusRoute = %@", [BusRoute objectAtIndex: i]);
    NSDictionary *dic = [BusRoute objectAtIndex: i];
    NSMutableArray *paths = [dic valueForKey:@"PATH"];
}
```

Comment: There's only one object inside your array, and it's a string. Your problem is removing these characters from the string, not objects from an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide that your object in the array path is string, you can do this

```
NSMutableArray *path2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:nil];
for (NSObject *obect in path) {
    for (NSString *string in (NSArray*)obect) {
        [path2 addObject:[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@","]];
    }

}

NSLog(@"pathArr %@ ",  path2);
```

your array paths contains an another array which has string as object.
Hope this helps

Comment: got an error for it `-[__NSArrayM stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x91ccc0`

Comment: can you paste your code? are you sure you called that function using string object?

Comment: wat do u mean? `[path2 addObject:[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@","]];` this line got the error

Comment: for (NSString *string in paths) did you used this condition

Comment: yup i used 
`NSMutableArray *path2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:nil];
for (NSString *string in paths) {
    [path2 addObject:[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@";"]];

}`

Comment: above code is provided that your array paths contains NSString object... so you are sure that it contains NSString object?

Comment: yup inside it are all strings. i have other same arrays inside the for loop and i used it else where an example; `NSString *boardDesc = [boardDescArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: your array paths contains an another array which has string as object, i have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

you may cast or convert paths to NSString and then do:

```
paths  = (NSString *) [paths stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@";"];
```

if this does't work, create new NSString instance that containing pathArr text, invoke replaceOccurrences method and do invert conversion

```
 NSMutableString *tempStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
 for (int i = 0; i < [paths count]; i++) 
{  
   [tempStr appendString:[path objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

then use this method for tempStr. And then try:

```
NSArray *newPaths = [tempStr componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

may be last method not completely correct, so try experiment with it.

Comment: Got a warning tat says`NSMutableArray may not respond to stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:with String`.

Answer (score 0):

//Copy the Array into a String

NSString *str = [paths componentsJoinedByString: @""];

//then replace the "|"

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"|" withString:@";"];

Answer (score 0):

i did this to replace a string in a .plist so it might work for you

```
    array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:Path1];
NSString *item = [@"dfdfDF"];
[array1 replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:item];

        [array1 writeToFile:Path1 atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"count: %@", [array1 objectAtIndex:1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uh, why don't you just go:

```
NSString *cleanedString = [[[dic valueForKey:@"PATH"] objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@"|"];
```

If there are more than one nested array, you can go

```
for(int i = 0; i < [[dic valueForKey:@"PATH"] count]; i++)
{
    NSString *cleanedString = [[[dic valueForKey:@"PATH"] objectAtIndex:i] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@"|"];

    // do something with cleanedString
}
```